# dont understand Linux command

Tags: php, linux, unix, grep

I'm working on existing php project and I'm totally beginner with that .

I 'm trying to understand this line of code .

```
exec("/usr/local/sbin/clog '/var/log/filter.log' | grep -F '10' | /usr/bin/tail -r -n 350 | grep -ve 'CLOG.*\033' | grep 'filterlog:'" , $logarr )
```

I've searched alot and I know that
exec is used to run unix command .

But I don't understand the first part **/usr/local/sbin/clog '/var/log/filter.log'**

I also dont understand **|** meaning here

also I don't understand this part **/usr/bin/tail -r -n 350**

can someone explain ?

Comment: `/usr/local/sbin` contains _binaries_, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/308045/differences-between-bin-sbin-usr-bin-usr-sbin-usr-local-bin-usr-local So in this instance, this is invoking the binary for the `clog` command from that directory. And it passes the file path `/var/log/filter.log` as an argument.

Comment: What `/usr/local/sbin/clog` is or does is anybodies guess. Since it's under `/usr/local` it obviously wasn't installed via a package manager - ask whoever set this up what it does.

Comment: P.S.: Is this `linux` or `unix`? You have both tags, but it obviously can't be both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` is the [pipe operator](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02). It takes the output of the command to its left and feeds it as input to the command on the right.

`/usr/local/sbin/clog` is the path to a binary called [`clog`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/clog.1.html). It can colorize log files. The binary is started with one positional parameter `'/var/log/filter.log'`, which is the path to a log file.

`/usr/bin/tail` is another binary called [`tail`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html), which displays the last N lines (350 lines in your example). The `-r` switch might indicate that this is running under BSD operating system? Here is a note from the tail documentation about the `-r` switch:

> GNU ‘tail’ can output any amount of data (some other versions of ‘tail’ cannot).  It also has no ‘-r’ option (print in reverse), since reversing a file is really a different job from printing the end of a file; BSD ‘tail’ (which is the one with ‘-r’) can only reverse files that are at most as large as its buffer, which is typically 32 KiB.  A more reliable and versatile way to reverse files is the GNU ‘tac’ command.

Both programs are started by their absolute path, presumably as a protection against wrong or empty values in `PATH`.